# Соединение insert into и join в одном запросе

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня в SQL Server есть базовая таблица с 10 столбцами:

dt/tm/order_number/order_type/product_category/product/manufacturer/cnt/price/selling_price

К ней создаю 4 справочника с id:

1. order_type_id
2. product_category_id
3. product_id
4. manufacturer_id

Запрос классический:

```
create table order_type
(
    order_type_id   int identity (1,1),
    order_type      varchar(200) not null
);

create table product_category
(
    product_category_id int identity (1,1),
    product_category    varchar(200)
);

create table product
(
    product_id  int identity (1,1),
    product     varchar(200)
);

create table manufacturer
(
    manufacturer_id int identity (1,1),
    manufacturer    varchar(200)
);
```

Затем создаю итоговую таблицу:

dt/tm/order_type_id/product_category_id/product_id/manufacturer_id/cnt/price/selling_price

В итоге в новую таблицу нужно вставить соответствующие данные из базовой таблицы и присоединить из справочников id:

```
INSERT INTO operations_data (dt, tm, order_type_id, cnt, price, selling_price)
SELECT dt, tm, order_type_id, cnt, price, selling_price
FROM invoice_order_operations AS ioo
INNER JOIN order_type AS ot ON ioo.order_type_id = ot.order_type_id
```

В итоге выдает ошибку:

> The multi-part identifier "operations_data.order_type_id" could not be
> bound

Сломал голову

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: вставить вам надо id, выбрав его по имени, чего вы тогда джойните талице по айдишнику, а не имени? В добавок, почему вы в джйоне используете таблицу, в котороую инсерт делаете, а не ту из которой данные?

Comment: вы без insert сначала сделайте нормальный select для подгтовки данных

Comment: `on order_type.order_type_id=operations_data.order_type_id` -> **operations_data** этой таблицы нет в select

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/Wu7iXrHQ. тут все мои действия с запросами. Зашился на этапе присоединения справочников к новой таблице. Есть ли варианты присоединения?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, Вы связываете не ту таблицу для выборки

```
--on order_type.order_type_id=operations_data.order_type_id
on order_type.order_type=invoice_order_operations.order_type
```

Однако, все записи будут каждый раз добавляться в таблицу)

Comment: Привет. Вчера уже разобрался в своей ошибке - не по той таблице присоединялся. Всем спасибо